# Can't extract text from html using SoupStrainer

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract `samsung galaxy s3 i9300` from the following html:

```
<a style="font-weight:bold;text-align:left; display: inline-block; height:25px;" href="product_info.php?type_id=1&amp;set_ad_type=&amp;product_id=5819985">samsung galaxy s3 i9300</a>
```

using Beautiful Soup and SoupStrainer. Tried to filter down with
`('a'{'style': 'font-weight:bold;'})` but no luck. What would be the precise Strainer here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also rely on the container that holds the link, or sibling elements..could you post more html code you have to parse? (or a link to a website you are scraping). Thanks.

Comment: You could do it searching by link text match

Comment: @alecxe here is the link to screenshot of the DOM part:

http://imgur.com/GGTQvKa

Comment: @Vkt0rS. Could you please tell more about that or provide with the link to that method?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a value for `href`, Beautiful Soup will filter against each tag’s `href`attribute:

```
soup.find_all(href=re.compile("product_info.php?"))
```

This returns all the `href` with this word contained.

Or you can do something like this

```
# TEXT is the text you want to find, or you combine it with re like the above example
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True, text='TEXT'):
```

An this will return all the `a` with contains a `href` adn the text is `TEXT`.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

The second method probably not gonna work because there are other titles from other products on the same page nested with the similar pattern and 'TEXT' method won't show them. i.e. samsung, iphone, htc, blackberry and so on. 

But I can't wait to get home and test the first one! Thanks again!

Comment: But the question was about using SoupStrainer to do this.